# Resizable In-Line Image on QTextEdit

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit, qpixmap

I'm working on an in-line widget for the QTextEdit to enable resizing via the QSizeGrip and 90 degree rotation via a context menu. I've been able to render a QLabel inside, but it loses its regular functionality. The question is how to properly embed a QWidget in a QTextEdit using the QTextObjectInterface?

https://blog.rfox.eu/en/Programming/Python/Active_widget_in_PyQT5_-_QTextEdit.html

Related question for C++
[How to resize an image in a QTextEdit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720502/how-to-resize-an-image-in-a-qtextedit)

Replace "picture.jpg" with a local file to get the example going.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QSizeF, QRectF, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextObjectInterface, QTextFormat, QTextCharFormat, QTextDocument, QPainter, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QSizeGrip


class InLineWidget(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(InLineWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        w, h = self.width(), self.height()
        p = QPixmap(r"picture.jpg")
        self.setPixmap(p)

        self.setMinimumSize(1, 1)
        # self.setScaledContents(False)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.SubWindow)
        sizeGrip = QSizeGrip(self)
        # self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        # self.setScaledContents(True)
        # self.setFrameStyle(3)
        # self.setFixedSize(500, 600)
        # self.setMinimumSize(10, 10)
        # self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 40%)")
        # self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)


class ImageObject(QObject, QTextObjectInterface):
    IMAGE_TYPE = QTextFormat.UserObject + 2

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImageObject, self).__init__(parent)

    def drawObject(self, painter: QPainter, rect: QRectF, doc: QTextDocument, posInDocument: int,
                   format: QTextFormat) -> None:
        w = format.property(2)
        w.render(painter, rect.topLeft().toPoint())

    def intrinsicSize(self, doc: QTextDocument, posInDocument: int, format: QTextFormat) -> QSizeF:
        w = format.property(2)
        return QSizeF(w.size())


class TextEdit(QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TextEdit, self).__init__()
        self.img_interface = ImageObject()
        self.img_interface.setParent(self)

        layout = self.document().documentLayout()
        layout.registerHandler(ImageObject.IMAGE_TYPE, self.img_interface)


class TestWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.te = TextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.te)
        self.btn_img = QPushButton('add picture', clicked=self.addPic)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_img)

    def addPic(self):
        image = InLineWidget()
        image.setParent(self.te)

        imgCharFormat = QTextCharFormat()
        imgCharFormat.setObjectType(ImageObject.IMAGE_TYPE)
        imgCharFormat.setProperty(2, image)

        cursor = self.te.textCursor()
        cursor.insertText(chr(0xfffc), imgCharFormat)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = TestWidget()

    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to use the QSizeGrip to resize/rotate the QLabel? If that's so, you cannot, or at least not like this: the widget is not "actually" there: it's only *drawn* there. If you want image object manipulation, you need to interact with the mouse events or, better, the [`viewportEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewportEvent) in the QTextEdit subclass.

Comment: Attention: I have discovered the case we will encounter maximum recursion when we handler sizeGripper.When I handle `QTextEdit` widget instead of `QLabel`.As the final way, we make `imageHandler` disguise the widget by paint method in itself, and the size is updated at the `mouseReleaseEvent`. It is only one call for replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I have changed my previous code because of these problems.

1.We insert & reinsert inlineWidget in `mouseMoveEvent`, it causes overflow Error and maximum recursion error depending on what is the inlineWidget.In my case, I embed `QTextEdit`(subclasses for my own app) and implement the same action, but these errors have happened.
So I have judged the insertion should have been once.
I moved the code for insertion of new widget into `mouseReleaseEvent`.

2.For implementing 1 there is one problem. We insert inlinewidget at the `mouseReleaseEvent` only once, we cannot pay attention to & the picture of the image size on the way of resizing it. So, I mandate the action to `ImageHandler` paint func.

Please replace the example code to this.

```
class ImageHandler(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, rect = QRectF(), view=None):
        super(ImageHandler, self).__init__(rect)
        self.view = view
        self._color = QColor(200, 100, 200, 100)
    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        if hasattr(self, "inlinewidget"):
            #pixmap = QPixmap(r"self.inlinewidget.pixmap()") is more abstractive.
            pixmap = QPixmap(r"picture.jpg")
            pixmap =  pixmap.scaled(self.rect().size().toSize())
            painter.drawPixmap(self.rect().toRect(), pixmap)
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())
    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rect()
class ImageSizeGrip(ImageHandler):   
    def __init__(self, rect = QRectF(), view=None):
        super(ImageSizeGrip, self).__init__(rect, view)
        self.start_pos = QPointF()
        self.setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt.LeftButton)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.color = QColor(120, 243, 80, 200)
        self.setFlags(QGraphicsRectItem.ItemIsSelectable|QGraphicsRectItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.grab_textobject = False
        self.find_cursor = QTextCursor()
        self.find_position = 0
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.start_pos = event.scenePos()
        cur = self.parentItem().inlinewidget.parent().cursorForPosition(self.parentItem().inlinewidget.geometry().bottomRight())
        doc = self.parentItem().inlinewidget.parent().document()
        
        self.find_cursor = doc.find(chr(0xfffc), cur.position(), doc.FindBackward)
        self.find_position = self.find_cursor.position()
        self.find_cursor.clearSelection()             
        self.find_cursor.setPosition(self.find_position, self.find_cursor.MoveAnchor)
        self.find_cursor.movePosition(self.find_cursor.Left, self.find_cursor.KeepAnchor)
        return QGraphicsRectItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        parentItem = self.parentItem()
        parentItem.prepareGeometryChange()
        rect = QRectF()
        rect.setCoords(parentItem.rect().topLeft().x(), parentItem.rect().topLeft().y(), event.scenePos().x(), event.scenePos().y())
        parentItem.setRect(rect)
        parentItem.update() 
        self.find_cursor.clearSelection()
        self.find_cursor.setPosition(self.find_position, self.find_cursor.MoveAnchor)
        return QGraphicsRectItem.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        parentItem = self.parentItem()
        self.find_cursor.movePosition(self.find_cursor.Left, self.find_cursor.KeepAnchor)
        if self.find_cursor.selectedText() == chr(0xfffc) and  len(self.find_cursor.selectedText()) == 1:
            self.find_cursor.setKeepPositionOnInsert(True)           
            self.find_cursor.deleteChar()
            inLineWidget = InLineWidget()
            inLineWidget.setGeometry(parentItem.rect().toRect())
            parentItem.inlinewidget.parent().insert_text_object(self.find_cursor, inLineWidget)        
            self.find_cursor.setKeepPositionOnInsert(False)
            parentItem.inlinewidget.parent()._trigger_obj_char_rescan()
        self.view.scene().removeItem(self.parentItem())
        self.view.scene().removeItem(self)
        self.view.scene().update()
        return QGraphicsRectItem.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        return QGraphicsRectItem.hoverEnterEvent(self, event)
    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):        
        return QGraphicsRectItem.hoverLeaveEvent(self, event)
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

<sub>I have judged the update of question is the last, so I want to write my answer with assumption.</sub>

At least, if you want to embed the same size pic on the widget, you must scale it in proportion to the parent widget.

for doing this, you must add the code for scaleing.

```
w.setPixmap(w.pixmap().scaled(w.size()))
```

Then, you want to resize the widget by `QSizeGrip`.
you also want to resize the embedded image.

`QTextObjectInterface` can draw `QTextObject` but it is not interactive.
According to the url on your question, you must render the `QSizeGrip` widget too.

and you forgot to write this code in `def addPic(self):`

```
image.show()
```

But as for only this, two dimentional images are drawn. One is drawn by `drawObject`, the other is pixmap object embedded by 'InlineWidget`.(One = A, the other = B)

Now, you draw a widget, but this is a special case. Originally, `QTextObjectInterface` is prepared for drawing an uninteractive object as if it were a character.Certainly, whatever you can paint, it can draw.But normally, we don't use it for drawing an interactive widget.
You have begun from the special case.It is making us difficult to recognize where is the problem.
[image]

you will manage to confirm what is happened under the duplicate picture because of meaningless sentence.
'A' is drawn by `drawObject`. 'B' is only shown, but has parent of `QTextEdit`, so to speak, it is an only widget.Our text-handling has no influence on 'B'.

If you add some texts, 'A' is slided gradually by texts because it is truely `TextObject`.
But 'B' is not slided because it is not TextObject but `QWidget`.

In advantage of automatic calculation of `QTextObjectInterface`, we must coincide the position of 'B'  to that of 'A'. We must add this code in `drawObject`.

```
w.move(rect.topLeft().toPoint())
```

From these steps, you could embed your picture as the size of it as much as that of widget, show interactive widget,  move `InLineLabel` against picture and picture itself in parallel.

When you show the widget, I think `inlined_widget.widget.render(painter, rect.topLeft().toPoint())` in `drawObject()` has been already needless because widget works in behalf of it.

---

From now on, I change your code largely.

Even if you add the above-mentioned repaired code, there are many problems to be remained if you want to resize the image.

1. `QSizeGrip` is difficult to handle in this case for this purpose. I highly recommend handling by `QGraphicsView`, `QGraphicsScene`, `QGraphicsItem`.(I don't know how to use `QSizeGrip`, as far as I look your code, this is at the topLeft corner. I think this should be placed at the bottomRight corner.and I couldn't catch the coordinate system soon.I assume this happens because the geometry of `InLineWidget` is not yet decided.It is decided when it is inserted.But QSizeGrip is already a child of it.) I tried to implement `QSizeGripEnabled(True)` of `QDialog`, even I set it False, I can resize the dialog...
2. If we resize the widget, the embedded pixmap will be resized. But `jpg` file will be collapsed easily if it is on the same memory because of the result of accumulation of coarse, approximate recalculating.We need to reload the new, same name pixmap and scale the size, and swap.
3. Even If we delete the `TextObject` 'A' by deleting, copying, shearing, and so on, the widget 'B' will be still remained.We need to implement the way of deleting the widget and the basic object simultaneously.
4. To resize from 'B', certainly, you can resize it, but 'A' is not resized. Hence, to resize 'B' has no influence on the line space.We may resize from the both approach, but I take the way of 'B'.We need to make the change of 'B' have influence on 'A'.For doing it, we must exchange & update 'A' following the second URL.we need to resize 'B' , delete 'A' and reinsert 'A' simultaneously.

For solving these problems, we need to implement the procedure of the URLs at least.
Thanks to widget, it is much easier to accept mouse handling. It serves as a proxy and getter of geometry.

Here is hybrid code with your introduced urls, yours and mine.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QSizeF, QRectF, Qt, QPointF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextObjectInterface, QTextFormat, QTextCharFormat, QTextDocument, QPainter, QPixmap, QPageSize, QBrush, QColor, QTextCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsRectItem, QSizeGrip


class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(View, self).__init__(parent)       
        self.imageHandler = ImageHandler(QRectF(), self)
        self.sizeGripHandler = ImageSizeGrip(QRectF(), self)
        self.sizeGripHandler.setParentItem(self.imageHandler)
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        self.scene().removeItem(self.imageHandler)
        self.scene().removeItem(self.sizeGripHandler)
        return QGraphicsView.keyPressEvent(self, event)
class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Scene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.gray, Qt.SolidPattern))
        
    def addItem(self, item):
        if item not in self.items():
            super(Scene, self).addItem(item)
    def removeItem(self, item):
        if item  in self.items():
            super(Scene, self).removeItem(item)
class ImageHandler(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, rect = QRectF(), view=None):
        super(ImageHandler, self).__init__(rect)
        self.view = view
        self._color = QColor(200, 100, 200, 100)
    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(self._color, Qt.Dense1Pattern))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())
    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rect()
    
class ImageSizeGrip(ImageHandler):
   
    def __init__(self, rect = QRectF(), view=None):
        super(ImageSizeGrip, self).__init__(rect, view)
        self.start_pos = QPointF()
        self.setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt.LeftButton)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.color = QColor(120, 243, 80, 200)
        self.setFlags(QGraphicsRectItem.ItemIsSelectable|QGraphicsRectItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.grab_textobject = False
        self.find_cursor = QTextCursor()
        self.find_position = 0
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.start_pos = event.scenePos()
        cur = self.parentItem().inlinewidget.parent().cursorForPosition(self.parentItem().inlinewidget.geometry().bottomRight())
        doc = self.parentItem().inlinewidget.parent().document()
        #chr(0xfffc) is probably located in the previous positions because ImageSizeGrip is positioned at the rightbottom of the picture.
        self.find_cursor = doc.find(chr(0xfffc), cur.position(), doc.FindBackward)
        self.find_position = self.find_cursor.position()
        self.find_cursor.clearSelection()             
        self.find_cursor.setPosition(self.find_position, self.find_cursor.MoveAnchor)
        movable = self.find_cursor.movePosition(self.find_cursor.Left, self.find_cursor.KeepAnchor)
        return QGraphicsRectItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        parentItem = self.parentItem()
        parentItem.prepareGeometryChange()
        rect = QRectF()
        rect.setCoords(parentItem.rect().topLeft().x(), parentItem.rect().topLeft().y(), event.scenePos().x(), event.scenePos().y())
        parentItem.setRect(rect)
        parentItem.inlinewidget.resize(rect.size().toSize())
        parentItem.update()
        #I think it is better you load initial pixmap item. Especially jpg is subject to be broken by size change.
        pixmap = QPixmap(r"picture.jpg")
        pixmap =  pixmap.scaled(rect.size().toSize())
        parentItem.inlinewidget.pixmap().swap(pixmap)
        self.find_cursor.clearSelection()
        self.find_cursor.setPosition(self.find_position, self.find_cursor.MoveAnchor)
        movable = self.find_cursor.movePosition(self.find_cursor.Left, self.find_cursor.KeepAnchor)
        if self.find_cursor.selectedText() == chr(0xfffc) and  len(self.find_cursor.selectedText()) == 1:
            self.find_cursor.setKeepPositionOnInsert(True)           
            self.find_cursor.deleteChar()
            inLineWidget = InLineWidget()
            inLineWidget.setGeometry(parentItem.rect().toRect())
            parentItem.inlinewidget.parent().insert_text_object(self.find_cursor, inLineWidget)        
            self.find_cursor.setKeepPositionOnInsert(False)
            parentItem.inlinewidget.parent()._trigger_obj_char_rescan()
        return QGraphicsRectItem.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.view.scene().removeItem(self.parentItem())
        self.view.scene().removeItem(self)
        self.view.scene().update()
        return QGraphicsRectItem.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        return QGraphicsRectItem.hoverEnterEvent(self, event)
    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):        
        return QGraphicsRectItem.hoverLeaveEvent(self, event)
class InLineWidget(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(InLineWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.view = None
        #Now, you are using only one picture. but if you set it as variable, you can set any pixmap item.
        p = QPixmap(r"picture.jpg")
        self.setPixmap(p)
        self.setMinimumSize(1, 1)
        # self.setScaledContents(False)
        # self.setWindowFlags(Qt.SubWindow)
        sizeGrip = QSizeGrip(self)
        sizeGrip.setWindowFlags(Qt.SubWindow)
        # self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        # self.setScaledContents(True)
        self.setFrameStyle(3)
        # self.setFixedSize(500, 600)
        # self.setMinimumSize(10, 10)
        # self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 40%)")
        # self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.view.imageHandler.setRect(QRectF(self.geometry()))        
        self.view.sizeGripHandler.setRect(QRectF(self.view.imageHandler.rect().bottomRight(), QSizeF(10, 10)))
        self.view.sizeGripHandler.setPos(0, 0)
        self.view.scene().addItem(self.view.imageHandler)
        self.view.scene().addItem(self.view.sizeGripHandler)        
        self.view.imageHandler.inlinewidget = self
        return QLabel.mousePressEvent(self, event)    

class InlinedWidgetInfo:
    #From your pasting URL
    object_replacement_character = chr(0xfffc)
    _instance_counter = 0
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget
        self.text_format_id = QTextFormat.UserObject + InlinedWidgetInfo._instance_counter
        self.char = self.object_replacement_character
        InlinedWidgetInfo._instance_counter += 1

class TextEdit(QTextEdit):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(TextEdit, self).__init__()
        #From your pasting URL, but some valiables belong to QTextEdit.
        self.last_text_lenght = 0
        self.text_format_id_to_inlined_widget_map = {}
        self.currentCharFormatChanged.connect(self.on_character_format_change)
        self.selectionChanged.connect(self._trigger_obj_char_rescan)
        self.textChanged.connect(self.on_text_changed)
    
    def wrap_with_text_object(self, inlined_widget):       
        class ImageObject(QObject, QTextObjectInterface):       
            def __init__(self, parent=None):
                super(ImageObject, self).__init__(parent)        
            def drawObject(self, painter: QPainter, rect: QRectF, doc: QTextDocument, posInDocument: int,
                           format: QTextFormat) -> None:
                
                # inlined_widget.widget.render(painter, rect.topLeft().toPoint())
                inlined_widget.widget.setGeometry(rect.toRect())
            def intrinsicSize(self, doc: QTextDocument, posInDocument: int, format: QTextFormat) -> QSizeF:               
                return QSizeF(inlined_widget.widget.size())
        document_layout = self.document().documentLayout()
        document_layout.registerHandler(inlined_widget.text_format_id, ImageObject(self))
        self.text_format_id_to_inlined_widget_map[inlined_widget.text_format_id] = inlined_widget
        inlined_widget.widget.setPixmap(inlined_widget.widget.pixmap().scaled(inlined_widget.widget.size()))

    def insert_text_object(self, cursor, inlined_widget):
        inlined_widget = InlinedWidgetInfo(inlined_widget)        
        self.wrap_with_text_object(inlined_widget)
        inlined_widget.widget.view = self.vi
        inlined_widget.widget.setParent(self)

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setObjectType(inlined_widget.text_format_id)
        cursor.insertText(inlined_widget.char, char_format)
        inlined_widget.widget.show()

    def on_character_format_change(self, qtextcharformat):
        text_format_id = qtextcharformat.objectType()
        
        # id 0 is used when the object is deselected - I don't really want the id
        # itself, I just want to know that there was some change AFTER it was done
        if text_format_id == 0:
            self._trigger_obj_char_rescan()

    def on_text_changed(self):
        current_text_lenght = len(self.toPlainText())
        if self.last_text_lenght > current_text_lenght:
            self._trigger_obj_char_rescan()

        self.last_text_lenght = current_text_lenght

    def _trigger_obj_char_rescan(self):
        text = self.toPlainText()
        character_indexes = [
            cnt for cnt, char in enumerate(text)
            if char == InlinedWidgetInfo.object_replacement_character
        ]

        # get text_format_id for all OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTERs
        present_text_format_ids = set()
        for index in character_indexes:
            cursor = QTextCursor(self.document())

            # I have to create text selection in order to detect correct character
            cursor.setPosition(index)
            if index < len(text):
                cursor.setPosition(index + 1, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)

            text_format_id = cursor.charFormat().objectType()

            present_text_format_ids.add(text_format_id)

        # diff for characters that are there and that should be there
        expected_text_format_ids = set(self.text_format_id_to_inlined_widget_map.keys())
        removed_text_ids = expected_text_format_ids - present_text_format_ids

        # hide widgets for characters that were removed
        for text_format_id in removed_text_ids:
            inlined_widget = self.text_format_id_to_inlined_widget_map[text_format_id]
            inlined_widget.widget.hide()
            del self.text_format_id_to_inlined_widget_map[text_format_id]
class TestWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vi = View()
        self.sc = Scene()
        self.te = TextEdit()
        self.te.vi = self.vi
        self.te.resize(int(QPageSize.size(QPageSize.A0, QPageSize.Point).width()), int(QPageSize.size(QPageSize.A0, QPageSize.Point).height()))
        self.sc.addWidget(self.te)
        self.vi.setScene(self.sc)
        self.vi.setSceneRect(QRectF(0, 0, int(QPageSize.size(QPageSize.A0, QPageSize.Point).width()), int(QPageSize.size(QPageSize.A0, QPageSize.Point).height())))
        layout.addWidget(self.vi)
        self.btn_img = QPushButton('add picture', clicked=lambda:self.te.insert_text_object(self.te.textCursor(), InLineWidget()))
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_img)
        self.vi.centerOn(0 ,0)
    def addPic(self):
        # is not used
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = TestWidget()

    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Change Point**

I think you will probably understand where to be changed.

1. `QGraphicsView` is newly imported for viewing `QGraphicsItem`.
2. `QTextEdit` was fit into the `QGraphicsView` & `QGraphicsScene`.
3. To Implement the URLs codes for deleting widgets cleanly.
4. To Implement the way of the second url for exchanging `QTextObject`, aligning it dynamic bottom of `QTextLine`.

If you have some questions , please comment.

Thanks to easily understandable & readable coding of your URL, it was very easy to dock codes.

If you embed multiple images, the bottom line of each image is forcibly aligned at the largest bottom of at the current `QTextLine`.So you will look an odd moving when you are resizing.But it will be difficult to solve it as long as the images are `QTextInlineObject`.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer, this is a perfect solution and will be helpful to many attempting to extend QTextEdit.

Comment: Adding transformMode = Qt.SmoothTransformation to pixmap().scaled can give better visual results, I'm looking at ways to keep the aspect ratio constrained..